# Why does Google Cloud Function HTTP need a parameter in the main function?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

In Google Cloud Function (http).

Why does this work :

```
def hello_world(a):
    return f'Hello World!'
```

but not this :

```
def hello_world():
    return f'Hello World!'
```

Comment: Your code samples look identical to me.

Comment: @DougStevenson, you didn't see the difference???? Me neither :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cloud function need the request parameter, in case you have to use the request data (get or post data) to process them in your function. The interface contract requires 1 parameter. that's the deal, else it doesn't work

Comment: So it's just "like this" by design, thank you